# The type arguments for method GroupJoin cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm quite new to using Entity Framework and I keep running into this problem where my code can't compile. The error message I get is:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupJoin(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,TResult>>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I've done some search and found some similar problems but nothing has helped me fix my problem. I'm just trying to output something simple for debugging purposes here is the code I have at the moment:

```
var result = _context.Set<User>()
             .Where(user => user.GraphMeetingStatistics && user.Id == userId)
             .GroupJoin(_context.Set<Meeting>()
                 .Where(meeting => meeting.UserId == userId),
                 user => user.Id,
                 meeting => meeting.Guid,
                 (user, meeting) => meeting);
```

I'd appreciate any help with this error

Comment: Are `user.Id` and `meeting.Guid` of the same type?

Comment: No user.Id is an int and meeting.Guid is a Guid

Comment: Well, that's your problem. For a join (or a group join), the ids must have the same type, since they must be matched. If you just want the meetings for a specific user, you don't need a join, just get the meetings where `meeting.UserId == userId`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I think you have to join on `user.Id` and `meeting.UserId`.

Comment: Thomas' comment helped me fix it in the end. I ended up writing it a little differently but I kind of rethinked it and it's working fine now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

As indicated by [Thomas Levesque's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26481982/370671#comment41599873_26481982), the keys used to join the collections must be of the same type. So, in your case, `user.Id` and `meeting.Guid` are not the same type (`int` and `Guid`, respectively). You haven't provided information about the structure of these objects, so I can't tell you exactly how to update your code.

[DotNotPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/groupjoin) has a good, basic overview of of how `GroupJoin` works, and describes the arguments as such:

> **Arguments 1 and 2:**
>
> Argument one is the secondary collection. And
>   argument two is a `Func` that returns the key from the first object
>   type.
>
> **Arguments 3 and 4:**
>
> A `Func` that returns the key from the second object
>   type, and one that stores the grouped object with the group itself.